# Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $X^0\subseteq X$. (as in topology of $\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

- Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $X^0\subseteq X$.

*Recall.* Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $x_0\in X$. $x_0$ is a interior point of $X$ if there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\left( x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta\right) \subseteq X$. $X^0$ is the set of all interior points.

I will show that $X^0\subseteq X$. Let $x_0\in X^0$. Then, by the definition, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\left( x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta\right) \subseteq X$. **Hence, how can I show final step, that is, $x_0\in X$?**

**Can we say that let $t\in\left( x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta\right) \subseteq X$. Hence, $t\in X^0$ and $t\in X$. Thus,$X^0\subseteq X$?**

Comment: Since $x_0\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\subset X$ your are finished.

Comment: @humanStampedist I added final step, can you see?

Comment: @humanStampedist but $x_0\notin\left( x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta\right) \subseteq X$?

Comment: $x_0\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, since $x_0-\delta < x_0 < x_0+\delta$. If you just take $t=x_0$ in your argument, it would shorten significantly.

Comment: @humanStampedist thanks.